# Binary Search Tree Deletion in Python Recursive

Tags: python, search, tree, binary

I know this question has been asked hundreds of times, but I haven't been able to find a question exactly similar to my implementation of binary search trees. I have implemented a basic binary search tree class in Python; the only function that currently is not complete is the delete function. I understand the algorithm for how it is done, and the three different deletion cases. The one restriction I have is that I don't want to use parent pointers, and I am unsure how to keep track of the previous node so that I can set it appropriately based on deletion.

For example, for the case where the node to be deleted has one child, I don't know how I can keep track of the previous node (parent node) so that I can update its left or right child to the children of the node that was deleted.

**I don't want to use parent pointers for each node in this deletion function**

```
    def delete(self, value):
        if self.root:
            self.__delete(value, self.root)

    def __delete(self, value, curr_node):
        #How do I keep track of previous (parent) node here?
        if curr_node:
            if value < curr_node.value:
                self.__delete(value, curr_node.left)
            elif value > curr_node.value:
                self.__delete(value, curr_node.right)
            elif value == curr_node.value:
                #Case 1: Node is leaf (no children)
                #Case 2: Node has one child: the parent node has its child updated to the deleted node's children
                #Case 3: Node has two children 
                pass
```

Full code

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, value):        
        if not self.root:
            self.root = Node(value)
        else:
            self.__insert(value, self.root)

    def __insert(self, value, curr_node):
        if value < curr_node.value:
            if not curr_node.left:
                curr_node.left = Node(value)
            else:
                self.__insert(value, curr_node.left)
        elif value > curr_node.value:
            if not curr_node.right:
                curr_node.right = Node(value)
            else:
                self.__insert(value, curr_node.right)
        else:
            print("Node already exists!")

    def lookup(self, value):
        if value == self.root.value:
            return self.root
        else:
            self.__lookup(value, self.root)

    def __lookup(self, value, curr_node):
        if value < curr_node.value:
            if value == curr_node.left.value:
                return curr_node.left
            else:
                self.__lookup(value, curr_node.left)
        elif value > curr_node.value:
            if value == curr_node.right.value:
                return curr_node.right
            else:
                self.__lookup(value, curr_node.right)
        else:
            print("Value doesn't exist!")

    def height(self):
        if not self.root:
            return 0
        else:
            return self.__height(self.root)

    def __height(self, curr_node):
        if not curr_node:
            return 0 
        return 1 + max(self.__height(curr_node.left), self.__height(curr_node.right))

    def min_value(self):
        if self.root:
            return self.__min_value(self.root)

    def __min_value(self, curr_node):
        if not curr_node.left:
            return curr_node

        return self.__min_value(curr_node.left)

    def max_value(self):
        if self.root:
            return self.__max_value(self.root)

    def __max_value(self, curr_node):
        if not curr_node.right:
            return curr_node
        return self.__max_value(curr_node.right)

    def count_nodes(self):
        if not self.root: 
            return 0 
        else:
            return self.__count_nodes(self.root)

    def __count_nodes(self, curr_node):
        if not curr_node:
            return 0 

        return 1 + self.__count_nodes(curr_node.left) + self.__count_nodes(curr_node.right)

    def inorder_traversal(self):
        if self.root:
            return self.__inorder_traversal(self.root)

    def __inorder_traversal(self, curr_node):
        path = []

        if curr_node:
            path.extend(self.__inorder_traversal(curr_node.left))
            path.append(curr_node.value)
            path.extend(self.__inorder_traversal(curr_node.right))

        return path

    def __num_children(self, curr_node):
        if not curr_node.left and not curr_node.right:
            return 0
        elif curr_node.right or curr_node.left:
            return 1
        elif curr_node.right and curr_node.left:
            return 2

    def delete(self, value):
        if self.root:
            self.__delete(value, self.root)

    def __delete(self, value, curr_node):
        #How do I keep track of previous (parent) node here?
        if curr_node:
            if value < curr_node.value:
                self.__delete(value, curr_node.left)
            elif value > curr_node.value:
                self.__delete(value, curr_node.right)
            elif value == curr_node.value:
                #Case 1: Node is leaf (no children)
                #Case 2: Node has one child: the parent node has its child updated to the deleted node's children
                #Case 3: Node has two children 
                pass
```

Comment: You cannot do the deletion this way without parent pointers; you will have to delete the node when you are visiting its parent, not when you are visiting the node itself. So, instead of trying to delete the current node when `value == curr_node.value`, delete the left child when `value == curr_node.left.value` and delete the right child when `value == curr_node.right.value`. There are more details because of the three cases you identified, but this should get you going.